# get "Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord" using custom AsynchTask

Tags: android

I use custom AsynchTask:

```
public class AbstractDialogTask extends AbstractTask {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    startWaitingScreen();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    stopWaitingScreen(result);
}

private void startWaitingScreen() {
    //show waiting activity
}

private void stopWaitingScreen(Integer result) {
    //finish waiting activity
}
```

}

and while a operation is being executed the activity dialog is being shown.

But from time to time I get:

```
Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{  WaitingActivity}
```

And my waiting activity is not being closed.

What can cause the such behavior?